# Function never called but shown by gprof for C code?

Tags: c, profiling, gprof

I am having the upper issue and was wondering if this is a bug or I am using gprof wrong?

So as usual I compile my C code with -pg commands, and then after running it I do `gprof ./my_program gmon.out >> gmon.txt`. Then in the output I noticed one function consuming much memory, which however should not be possible as it doesn't do a lot.

```
 Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ks/call  Ks/call  name    
 18.65    688.75   688.75   597878     0.00     0.00  visited_vertex_case
```

I checked the output of my code, and there it turned out...the function is actually never called?! So I added a code line to terminate the program if using this function, just to be sure, and yes - it is never  called.

So how can a function be inside my gprof output, if it is never used??

Comment: Is it single thread single process application? No fork or so?

Comment: Yes, it is single threaded

Comment: could you check by debugging the program and putting a breakpoint at `visited_vertex_case` ?

Comment: Just by curiosity. Why are you using `>>` in `./my_program gmon.out >> gmon.txt`?

Comment: Marian has a point: this appends to your log, so you're reading old results maybe.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought I am just redirecting the output into a text file - well that was my intension? So how should I do it in that case?

Comment: The `>>` redirects and *appends*. Use single `>` to redirect and *overwrite*. If you use Bash I recommend you [read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), especially [the section about redirection](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION).

Comment: Ok, so was a stupid mistake in that case.. So just to clarify, what does >> append in that case to my output, such that I get those wrong outputs???

Comment: There’s a moderate chance that the wrong function is being tagged with the time. IIRC, the profiling code spots the P.C. at the time of sampling and deduced which function should be attributed with the time used.  It can occasionally pick on the wrong function.  I’m a bit surprised that it is happening but not completely.